# How do I add or subtract the width of an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, width

I have a bar of which one half is red and other is green. I want it to subtract 1vw from the red element.

`style.width` does not work.

Here is my code:

```
//FIGHT
document.addEventListener("keydown", battle)
function battle(event){
   console.log(event.code)
   document.getElementById("ClickRed").style.width -= "1vw"

   }
```

Comment: what is the use case where you want to subtract `1vw` ?

Comment: First of all, `el.style.width` will __only return the width property in the style attribute__, if it exists. Second, you cannot subtract strings. You have to work with numbers, then convert it back to a string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` to get the total width and height that an element is taking up on the DOM. You can read more about [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)

To solve your particular usecase, i personally think that it would be better if you worked with pixels and not viewport width and height because `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` will return the width and height in pixels instead of `vw` and `vh`.

If you have your width and height in pixels, you can use it like this :-

```js
rb.style.width = `${rb.offsetWidth - 100}px`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("ClickRed").style.width=(parseFloat(document.getElementById("ClickRed").style.width) - 1) + "vw";
```